# Calling Overlay widget from appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I created an Overlay widget which works fine, but I don't know how to associate it with appbar. 
Like, if I click a button on the appbar, my Overlay container should show up in the body!

Comment: Yes, inside the scaffold body

Comment: Sorry to say, I used this package [overlay_container][https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_container] to use some custom Overlay functionality.

Comment: you have some sample code [here](https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_container#example) - doesn't it work?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I wanted to call the widget from appbar

Comment: you cannot "call the widget" - all you can do is to place it as a child of some other widget, like in the example: `OverlayContainer` is a child of some `Column` widget - so after the interaction with app bar rebuild your widgets tree including your `OverlayContainer` somewhere

Comment: Doesn't that increase the complexity when using the entire page inside a statefulwidget

Comment: you dont need `StatefulWidget` - you can use `ValueListenableBuilder` / `AnimatedBuilder` etc

Comment: Yup, it works, thank you